# List.OrderByDescending results in duplicates

Tags: c#, linq

This is my code

```
var peaks = FindPeaks(lfw, peakwidth);


var peaksordered = peaks.OrderByDescending(x => x.Value)
  .ThenBy(x => x.Frequency)
  .Distinct().ToList();

foreach (var mmm in peaksordered)
{
    Console.WriteLine(mmm.Frequency + ";" + mmm.Value);

}
return;
```

FindPeaks returns a `List<FrequencyValue>` which looks like this

```
public class FrequencyValue
{
    public double Frequency { get; set; }
    public double Value { get; set; }
}
```

When using the foreach with `peaks`, I get something like

```
12,3;0,4
14,5;0,7
...
```

As it should be. But if I use it the way mentioned I get only one result - or - if I omit the `.Distinct()` I get something like

```
12,3;0,4
12,3;0,4
12,3;0,4
12,3;0,4
12,3;0,4
12,3;0,4
12,3;0,4
12,3;0,4
12,3;0,4
....
```

Only duplicates. What do I need to change for ordering to work?

PS: Findpeaks:

```
    public static IEnumerable<FrequencyValue> FindPeaks(IEnumerable<FrequencyValue> lfw, int width)
    {
        FrequencyValue peak = new FrequencyValue();
        peak.Value = 0;
        int decay = 0;

        foreach (var value in lfw)
        {
            if (value.Value > peak.Value || decay > width / 2)
            {
                peak.Value = value.Value;
                peak.Frequency = value.Frequency;
                decay = 0;
            }
            else
                decay++;

            if (decay == width / 2)
                    yield return peak;
        }
    }
```

Comment: where does `FindPeaks` come from? is this EF or linq to sql?

Comment: Here's a tip from a fellow German: try coding in English. That makes it easier to get help and is an important skill.

Comment: @DanielA.White I added FindPeaks.

Comment: To me it seems that FindPeaks return duplicates, it even seems to return the same object more than once.  I think the problem is in FindPeaks.

Comment: Okay, you should create a new peak instance for every yield return.  You should not reuse it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your FindPeaks should look like this:

```
public static IEnumerable<Frequenz_und_Wert> FindPeaks(IEnumerable<Frequenz_und_Wert> lfw, int breite)
{
    int decay = 0;

    Frequenz_und_Wert peak = new Frequenz_und_Wert();
    peak.Wert = 0;
    foreach (var value in lfw)
    {
        if (value.Wert > peak.Wert || decay > breite / 2)
        {
            peak.Wert = value.Wert;
            peak.Frequenz = value.Frequenz;
            decay = 0;
        }
        else
            decay++;

        if (decay == breite / 2)
        {
                yield return peak;
                peak = new  Frequenz_und_Wert(){Wert = peak.Wert, Frequenz = peak.Frequenz};
        }
    }
}
```

The reason why the sorting is not working is that you keep overwriting the same instance, you need to return a new instance of Frequenz_und_Wert for every yield return.

Comment: Maybe, I do not understand what you method does and how it works, but you need to return new instances of Frequenz_und_Wert for every yield return - I have corrected the answer, hopefully this will help.

Comment: @DeadGirl No, it does not work.  It is returning a bunch of references to the same object and mutating that object as it iterates.  That's not "working", and it is clearly the source of your problems.  You seem to think that the sorting is the cause of your problems, but it's not, it's merely the means of exposing the existing problems to you.

Answer (score 1):

**You've got two bugs cancelling each other out.** This is very confusing.

Ordering is fine. Your `Distinct` is doing reference comparisons so it does not delete duplicates. Implement `IEquatable<Frequenz_und_Wert>` and override `GetHashCode`.

In addition, you are always returning the same object instance from `FindPeaks`. That's why `Distinct` appears to work (although not the way you need it). It just collapses the entire list to one item (to the only different item).

`foreach` happens to work for you because the printing happens between moments you do a `yield return`. The loop will always print from the same object, but the object is being modified in between iterations.

Move `Frequenz_und_Wert peak = new Frequenz_und_Wert();` into the loop to create a new item for each iteration.

Comment: I don't understand your answer. If I omit Distinct, which removes duplicates I get all the duplicates which again proves that the ordering function returns only duplicates.

Comment: The ordering function does not create duplicates. It just seems like that because all similar values are now located together. If your theory was correct, Distinct should still remove the duplicates. But it doesn't. Therefore, Distinct is not working.

Comment: Bitte was? Distinct funktioniert doch.

Comment: Hm. I misread the question. Anyway, Distinct will not work for you. You need to fix that as well. And there's also a problem with FindPeaks.

Comment: @DeadGirl you can convince yourself that FindPeaks is not correct by calling `ToList` on its result before running a foreach loop: `foreach (var mmm in peaks.ToList())`. It will now print 100% duplicates. If you've got trouble understanding what's going on I'll explain.